# How to start a program without interrupting my current session?

Tags: command-line, 13.10, launcher, execute-command

I'am working on some code or document and I need an additional program like IntellJ e.g.
How can I start this program in the background without popping up and **interrupting** me on my work?
Often I start something to have it ready after I finished reading.

Comment: Here is a duplicate of your question. Notice how quality question and correct tag choice affects the quality of the answers.
http://superuser.com/questions/184734/how-can-i-stop-new-windows-from-popping-up-over-what-im-doing

Comment: As you notice Mr Command farming point professional, i was not able to put images in. In my opinion my question is understandable in what I actually need. Sry if you not got it an searching the fault on my question. My Tags are correct tags. I am using command-line or launcher on my Ubuntu-13.10. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to send current job to background

type `fg` to bring it back

Comment: where to press? it is not working in the terminal or then application starts.

Comment: It is meant to be used in the terminal, while you have something running.

Comment: it is not the answer. I do not search for &.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question I guess. So what you meant was that you don't want the focussed window to change when you open a new application? Please edit and clarify your question.

Comment: Like i sad. I writing reading an email, i start an application like thunderbird. I dont want to have thunderbird pop up. Just to start minimized in the background

Answer (score 0):

Am going to give my answer based on Gedit.

To have gedit run in the background, I type `gedit -b&` in the terminal.
The `-b` option is to tell it to run in the background.
The `&` sign means that it should continue running even after I have closed the terminal.

For IntellJ, you can type `man intellj` to check whether it has a 'running in the background' option and then use it with a & sign at the end.

Comment: no -b parameter for gedit. this does not work!